# How do I set up NGINX to redirect if my user is not logged in using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am trying to set up NGINX so that it redirects a user either based on whether they are logged in or not.

For example, say the site is https://example.com and a user arrives at this URL, if they are not logged in we want to show a marketing page with register actions etc.  If they are logged in, we want to send them right into the product.  This is the same model as github, bitbucket etc. We don't use a cookie for managing session state, so trying to detect cookie from NGINX is a non starter, that is managed on the server.

So my question is this. Can anyone recommend some recipes for nodeJS and NGINX that could give me some ideas to follow on how to set this up?  Do I need to create something specific at the nodeJS end to satisfy NGINX in order to tell it that the user is not logged in? Or can I achieve this with checks in NGINX? I'm trying to protect the application from the outside world as much as possible which is why NGINX is the choice we made.

I've spend quite a few days trying to figure this out and am still as stumped as when I started so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not mentioned how do you detect whether the user is logged in? You are not using cookies, are you using Authorization header?

Answer (score -1):

Nginx in this case is meant to serve as a reverse-proxy to your Node application. This is a perfectly fine setup. However the functionality you're describing (check if the user is logged in) is something you need to check at the **application-level** (Node), not the webserver-level (Nginx).

How you will check whether the user is logged in is dependent on your login system, which we don't know anything about other than that it doesn't use cookies (which is in fact a rather common way to do this).

Comment: This doesn't seem completely correct. Can we revisit this?  E.g., connection passes basic auth headers. I would think there is a way to have nginx detect whether the header exists or not -- and (possibly) redirect to an authentication server to do the rest.

Comment: @joej handling basic auth headers is a different question. Consider posting a new question if you haven't found answer to it.